# AVG Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i need help with mysql avg query!

Table f

```
ticker | avgvol | mc
```

Table l

```
ticker | vo2
```

following select query gives me a list with 20 values

```
SELECT f.avgvol / l.vo2 ds 
  from f
  join l
    on f.ticker = l.ticker 
   order 
    by mc desc 
 LIMIT 20
```

now i want to have the average value from above (limt 20) and tried following query .. but i get an error

```
SELECT avg(f.avgvol / l.vo2) 
FROM f 
JOIN l on f.ticker = l.ticker 
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM f ORDER BY f.mc DESC 
) <=20
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: Post error also ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next approach:

```
select AVG(ds) from
(select (f.avgvol / l.vo2) ds 
  from f
  join l
    on f.ticker = l.ticker 
  where l.vol2 <> 0
  order by mc desc 
LIMIT 20) data;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It is working! I get the right avg value! Just one question : as i also get warnings (warning division by zero) and as i dont have any zero in the limit 20 .. it is  doing the  f.avgvol / l.vo2   on all records in the database (as i have some zeros outside the limit 20)

Comment: One more question .. how would be the full query when i want to use the calculated AVG(ds) and select f.name where (f.avgvol / l.vo2) > AVG(ds)/100 x120  (20 percent bigger)

Comment: I just add where condition for prevent zero division warnings. And about your second question you should ask separate question

Answer (score 0):

why used nested query used `avg()` function into a single query like this:

```
SELECT avg(tb_finvizall.avgvol / tb_live.vo2) as ds
 from tb_finvizall join tb_live
 on tb_finvizall.ticker = tb_live.ticker
 order by mc desc LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Thanks! But your query is not considering the Limit 20 .. as its calculate the avg from the complete table